# Inverse Laplace Transformation Simple Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

I'm new to Inverse Laplace Transformation so, I need to know whether the following question is correctly solved or not..

Question:

1/(s+2)^3

Solution:

Multiplying and dividing by 2;

= 2/2(s+2)^3

now, since 2=2! so;

= 2!/2(s+2)^3

now, using formula n!/(s-a)^n+1

here taking a's value in minus i.e
a = -2 and n's value is 2

= 2!/2(s-(-2))^2+1

= t^(2)e^(-2t)    [since n!/(s-a)^n+1 = t^(n)e^(at)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, you want:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left( \dfrac{1}{(s+2)^3}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}t^2e^{-2t}$$

You must leave the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ term because you need it there to eliminate the $2!$ term. In other words, take the result I wrote and the result you wrote and find the Laplace Transform. What happens? Clear?

Comment: Yes, i got it.. thanks for the help..

Comment: Deserves a TU! +1

Comment: I know! It feels like time fast-forwarded since Thanksgiving; I can't believe it's almost Christmas!

Comment: I got some MSE "swag" today. I was emailed by SE community staff  the day I hit 100K, asking what my size, color preference, etc., informing me that they wanted to send me swag. They got backlogged, apparently, but today, it was delivered. They were really generous: hoodie sweatshirt, a t-shirt, a mug, a flash-drive, water bottle, decals, ... Made my day!

Comment: Happy POETS day, btw!! Wishing you a fantastic weekend!

Comment: Glad you're home now, too. I hope you can more or less coast through the new year, in terms of work load! You've had your share of work this past month alone!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, I am going to 'veg like a rock' for the next 1.5 weeks. Simple stuff like exercise, reading, relaxing, watching videos ... truly need a break and I hope you are doing the same!